# Determining whether $(x^2-3)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, polynomial-rings

I've got a question regarding abstract algebra and prime/maximal ideals. I need to determine whether $(x^2-3)$ is a maximal or prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. I have not yet been introduced to irreducibility, so I cannot make use of theorems about that.

I'm not quite sure how to get started. I thought maybe I could use long division, and I found we can get polynomials $q(x),r(x)q(x),r(x)$ such that $p(x)=q(x)(x^2-3)+r(x)p(x)=q(x)(x^2-3)+r(x)$ and $r(x)=ax+b$. But now I'm stuck. And I'm fairly certain it's supposed to be prime, so finding zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^2-3)$ for example didn't seem like a good idea either.

Could anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would show that $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-3) \cong \Bbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$, but i'm not sure if that's too advanced

Comment: How could one define such an isomorphism?

Comment: Send the equivalence class of $x$ to $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: It's enough to show $x$ isn't a unit in the quotient. If it was, we'd have polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, such that $xf(x)=(x^2-3)g(x)+1$. Can you see the problem there?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how $x$ being a unit means we can find such polynomials. I'd say, if x were a unit in the quotient, we can find polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ such that $xf(x) = 1$ where $f(x)$ is of the form $(x^2-3)g(x)$, so $xf(x) = 1 = x(x^2-3)g(x)$.

Comment: @Jason: In the quotient ring all polynomials of the form $(x^2-3)g(x)$ become equal to zero. Zero rarely works as an inverse of anything. You need the equation SteveD gave, because $x f(x)$ only needs to be equal to $1$ **modulo the ideal generated by** $x^2-3$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks. So $x$ is not a unit and therefore the quotient is not a field, hence the ideal is not maximal. Still need to find out whether it is prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach problems like this by using ring homomorphisms, and applying
the first isomorphism theorem
$$
R/\operatorname{ker}(f)\simeq \operatorname{Im}(f).
$$
Recall that

- $I$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $R$ iff $R/I$ is an integral domain, and
- $I$ is a maximal ideal of a commutative ring $R$ iff $R/I$ is a field.

Extended hints:

1. Can you show that the mapping $f: p(x)\mapsto \overline{p(0)}$ is a surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ to $\Bbb{Z}_3$? Looks like $x^2-3$ is in the kernel, but does it generate the kernel?
2. Can you show that the mapping $g: p(x)\mapsto p(\sqrt3)$ is a homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ to $\Bbb{R}$? Use long division to prove that
   this time $x^2-3$ generates the kernel (you will also need the fact that $\sqrt3$ is irrational). Can you show that the image of this ring homomorphism is an integral domain?

Answer (score 0):

The maximal ideals of $\mathbf Z[X]$ are  known: they're generated by $(p, f(X)$, where $p$ is a prime, and $f$ is a polynomial irreducible modulo $p$.

Comment: In my opinion this is a useless answer. The OP shouldn't learn the general form of maximal ideals in order to answer his question.

Comment: Everyone should know the form of maximal ideals in *this* ring froom my point of view.